# Highcharts: 3D Pie Chart - Floating datalabel with 0%

Tags: highcharts

When I run a chart using 3D with some series with 0%, the datalabel is floating in a incorrect place.

Example code:

```
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                allowPointSelect: true,
                cursor: 'pointer',
                depth: 35,
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    format: '{point.name}'
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            type: 'pie',
            name: 'Browser share',
            data: [
                ['Firefox',   45.0],
                ['IE',       55.0],
                ['Others',   0.0]
            ]
        }]
    });
});
```

Source: http://jsfiddle.net/tuyuumy7/1

Comment: This is a known bug: https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/3240, it's already fixed in trunk: http://jsfiddle.net/tuyuumy7/2/.

Comment: Thanks, this fix is not in official release 4.0.4, but we can use this last link.